# Flutter Parametric Equalizer Interactive Graph

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation, equalizer

I am designing a Parametric Equalizer app using Flutter. But I am not able to find a interactive graph through which I can change the shape of the graph through itself.

[I want to create something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tddGA.png)

If you have any solutions please help me.

I have tried searching a lot, but was not able find a solution.